# What is valid container?

Tags: java, swing

What does "valid" mean in this context?
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/howLayoutWorks.html

> A container can be valid (namely, isValid() returns true) or invalid. For a container to be valid,
>       all the container's children must be laid out already and must all be valid also. The 
>       Container.validate method can be used to validate an invalid container. This method triggers the
>       layout for the container and all the child containers down the component hierarchy and marks this 
>       container as valid.

Comment: hmmm would be better test for is isDisplayable() to check about its status, after (re)validating an invalid container

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
isValid()
```

Indicates that the container hierarchy has been laid out correctly as is currently defined by the layout manager (for example `BorderLayout`), for example if you removed a JButton from a JPanel at runtime then you should call `validate()` or `revalidate()` This tells the Swing layout manager to recalculate the layout for the current container and triggers a recursive action down the tree.

Just a note the `revalidate()` is the same as calling invalidate() then validate(). These operations for nested revalidate() can be expensive.

Answer (score 2):

"Valid" is an attribute of a container. A container can be valid or invalid. If C1 and C2 are containers and C2 is inside C1 and C2 is invalid, C1 is invalid too. If you call C1.validate(), C2 will become valid too. Note that C1 is not valid if C2 is not laid out already.

Answer (score 2):

In Swing when you create Component, it is not valid i.e. it's valid property is false. A component is said to be valid, when it's width, height, location and stuff has been determined. This is usually done by calling their validate() method, directly or indirectly. When we call validate() on containers, it will validate the container (if it is invalid) by calling its doLayout() method, which typically will invoke the LayoutManager. Now each child placed on this container will be validated recursively, so that the entire tree will be laid out and will become valid.